# What are the access permissions to create a asymmetric key in "AWS KMS"

Tags: amazon-web-services, rsa, amazon-kms, key-management

I am setting up AWS KMS. I have done encryption and decryption but I am trying to create an asymmetric key with an IAM User. This user should be only create keys so I am creating a new user. I have tried `AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser` and the policy shown below.

However, can't create -- it says access denied.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "kms:PutKeyPolicy",
                "kms:CreateAlias"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateAlias",
                "kms:CreateKey",
                "kms:DeleteAlias",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:GenerateRandom",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "iam:ListGroups",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "kms:CreateKey",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "tag:GetResources"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "kms:PutKeyPolicy",
                "kms:CreateAlias"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateAlias",
                "kms:CreateKey",
                "kms:DeleteAlias",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:GenerateRandom",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "iam:ListGroups",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "kms:CreateKey",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "kms:PutKeyPolicy",
                "kms:CreateAlias"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateAlias",
                "kms:CreateKey",
                "kms:DeleteAlias",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:GenerateRandom",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "iam:ListGroups",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "kms:CreateKey",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried this json files. Please help me.

Comment: You'd usually get "access denied to...." where the permission you don't have is shown. I'd imagine to create you'd need the `kms:Encrypt` permission at least.

Comment: Are you saying that you get the error when **creating** the policy, or when **using** the policy? Please provide the exact error message and tell us what you were doing when the error occurred.